# Crop out bottom of video in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to crop out the bottom portion of a video I'm using but my code isn't working, what am I missing?

```
<div class="video_header">
  <video id="homepage" width="1520" muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="rom_homepage_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

```
.video_header {
    position: relative;
    right: 9px;
}

#homepage {
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}
```

Comment: A good question, tricky to reproduce with just this code. I would try adding height to the `video`, and then add height to the `.video_header` div that is shorter than the video height. Then give that outer `.video_header` div `overflow: hidden`. The taller video inside will be cut off at the bottom by however much taller it is than its parent container. Hope that makes sense.